# slicing array element using node js / javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, slice

```js
let array1= [
"home/work/data.jpg",
"home/work/abc.jpg",
"home/work/doc/animal.pdf",
"home/work/doc/fish_pdf.pdf"
];

array1= array1.map((data)=>{
return data.slice(2,data.length).join("/");
});
console.log(array1);
```

i want to slice my array by "home/work/" so it look like this

```
["data.jpg",
 "abc.jpg",
 "doc/animal.jpg",
 "doc/fish_pdf.pdf"]
```

but its not working
when i am using just this line

```
data.slice(2);
```

then output look like this

```
let array1= [
"me/work/data.jpg",
"me/work/abc.jpg",
"me/work/doc/animal.pdf",
"me/work/doc/fish_pdf.pdf"
];
```

Comment: `.slice()` on a string returns a string. You cannot `.join()` a string.

Comment: Are you missing a `.split("/")` before the `.slice()`?

Comment: Do you want to remove "home/work" from each array element ?

Comment: yes @RonakChauhan that's why i was using slice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to replace with a static string 'home/work/'

```js
let array1= [
"home/work/data.jpg",
"home/work/abc.jpg",
"home/work/doc/animal.pdf",
"home/work/doc/fish_pdf.pdf"
];

let array2= array1.map((data)=>{
return data.replace('home/work/','');
});
console.log(array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let array1= [
"home/work/data.jpg",
"home/work/abc.jpg",
"home/work/doc/animal.pdf",
"home/work/doc/fish_pdf.pdf"
];

array1= array1.map((data)=>{
return data.split('home/work/',data.length)[1];
});
console.log(array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) before using [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

```js
let array1 = [
  "home/work/data.jpg",
  "home/work/abc.jpg",
  "home/work/doc/animal.pdf",
  "home/work/doc/fish_pdf.pdf",
];

array1 = array1.map((data) => {
  return data.split("/").slice(2, data.length).join("/");
});
console.log(array1);
```